# storing chr(3) to variable in python output showing junk values

Tags: python

I'm converting some of `ascii character` to chr, so i used `chr() function` in `python`. if execute `chr(3)` i'll get `'\x03'` the answer is correct.
when i execute below code i get some junk value

```
a=chr(3)
print a
```

output is:

```
♥
```

or sometimes output shows junk values.

please tell me how to convert this value to readable format.

please tell me this is very important for me.

Comment: What *would* you expect the correct output to be for the END OF TEXT character...?

Comment: i'm expecting output should show '\x03'

Comment: Don't convert it into a character, just do `a = "\\x{0:02x}".format(3)`

Comment: you can print it like this: print repr(a)

Comment: which python version are you using ? for me for 2.7.5 it is working fine

Comment: @sachinsaxena You must be simply doing `>>a` instead of `print a`

Comment: i'm also using python 2.7 repr(a) function is working thanks to all

Comment: That is not a junk value.  Looks like you are on Windows, because that is the third character in the code set.  Same as you get with `print "\3"`.  What else did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print it like this, using the [repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) function:

```
a=chr(3)
print repr(a)
```

output:

```
'\x03'
```

If you want to get rid of the quotes you could do this:

```
print repr(a)[1:-1]
```

output:

```
\x03
```